# Find the inverse (reciprocal) of a polynomial modulo another polynomial with coefficients in a finite field

Tags: python, sympy, galois-field

If I have a polynomial P, is there a way to calculate P^-1 modulo Q, being Q another polynomial? 
I know that the coefficients of both polynomials belongs to the field of integers modulo z, being z an integer.

I´m not sure if SymPy has already a function for that in its [galoistools](https://docs.sympy.org/0.7.6.1/_modules/sympy/polys/galoistools.html) module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially the same as finding polynomials S, T such that PS + QT = 1. Which is possible when gcd(P, Q) = 1, and can be done with [`galoistools.gf_gcdex`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/internals.html#sympy.polys.galoistools.gf_gcdex). For example, let's invert `3x^3+2x+4` modulo `x^2+2x+3` with the coefficient field Z/11Z:

```
from sympy.polys.domains import ZZ
from sympy.polys.galoistools import gf_gcdex

p = ZZ.map([3, 0, 2, 4])
q = ZZ.map([1, 2, 3])
z = 11
s, t, g = gf_gcdex(p, q, z, ZZ)
if len(g) == 1 and g[0] == 1: 
    print(s)
else:
    print('no inverse')
```

This prints `[8, 5]` - the inverse is `8x+5`. Sanity check by hand:

```
(3x^3+2x+4)*(8x+5) = 24x^4 + 15x^3 + 16x^2 + 42x + 20 
                   = 2x^4 + 4x^3 + 5x^2 + 9x + 9
                   = (x^2 + 2x + 3)*(2x^2 - 1) + 1
                   = 1 mod q
```